# How to programmatically swap the caps lock and esc keys?

Tags: gnome, command-line, keyboard

I am a heavy Vim user and one of the first things I do when I start working on a clean ubuntu installation is to swap the caps lock and esc keys to reduce hand movements over the keyboard.

So far I have been doing it through the keyboard configuration dialog, but I am now writting a set of scripts that will set Ubuntu up the way I like and I have not been able to find a *scriptable* or programmable way to change this configuration item.

I am not looking for options that swap the keys at any other level than gnome itself, so what I am looking for is for a way to script this change and have it appear in the keyboard configuration that I used to use, should I decide to revert it manually in the future.

Comment: nice idea! i've been complaining all the time about moving my hand for Esc while working in Vim, but now this is the solution! thanx bro ;-)

Comment: Be careful, though, once you get used to having them swapped, it gets awkward when you have to work on anybody else's keyboard :)

Comment: Another option is Ctrl-C instead of Esc. (Works on all keyboards.

Comment: @FarmBoy, awesome! I didn't know that one!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this through the GUI by open the `Keyboard Preferences` control panel (under `System -> Preferences`), and select the `Layout` tab.  Click on the `Options...` button to open the layout options dialog.  Expand the `Caps Lock key behaviour` section and select `Swap ESC and Caps Lock`.

There are a few ways you could script this kind of thing.

#### Directly via Xkb

We can make the change directly with the following:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

You can disable all the current layout options (which will return caps lock to its default behaviour) with:

```
setxkbmap -option ''
```

#### Via GConf

The keyboard preferences control panel stores its configuration via `gconf`, with the layout actually being applied by `gnome-settings-daemon`.  Therefore, you can cause `gnome-settings-daemon` to adjust the layout by updating gconf yourself.

The relevant setting in this case appears to be `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options`.  So you can set the option with:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options \
    --type list --list-type string \
    '[caps<tab>caps:swapescape]'
```

In the above, `<tab>` should be a literal tab character rather than spaces.  You can disable the behaviour again by setting the gconf key to an empty list.

Comment: The gconf option is exactly what I was looking for, however your configuration was turning the caps lock into an escape key and the escape key into a tab key. I changed the setting manually again and took a look at the value in gconf-editor, it was actually `[caps<tab>caps:swapescape]`. Everything works now, I'm accepting your answer and suggest that you edit it to change the value for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacobo In future, you may suggest the edit yourself - just hit the edit button below the answer. Your change will quickly be approved by someone. I've made the edit for you (check if it's right). Anyway, nice answer @James! +1

Comment: @Stefano, thank you, I hadn't noticed the edit option.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in GDM at the login screen?