# How can I disable Caps Lock on text-mode (tty) terminals?

Tags: command-line, tty, virtual-console, capslock

I have disabled caps lock in Ubuntu via the System Settings -> Keyboard panel (see [How to programmatically swap the caps lock and esc keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35890/how-to-programmatically-swap-the-caps-lock-and-esc-keys) on how to find this option), however when I switch to a text-mode tty terminals (through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) caps lock is no longer disabled.

I use these text-based terminals a fair amount - is there a way to *completely* disable Caps Lock, even on these terminals?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had success using the instructions posted on [this blog](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/remap-caps-lock-key-for-virtual-console.html) in a virtual console:

```
echo -e "$(dumpkeys | grep ^keymaps)\nkeycode 58 = Escape" | sudo loadkeys
```

I'm not sure how to apply this automatically after every reboot, though.

---

While researching your question, I also ran across this alternative solution:

[image: Disable Caps Lock]

Comment: I honestly have no idea what that command did, but it worked!  At some point I'll have to work my way through that blog post and understand it, but for now thanks!

Comment: After every reboot? Use `@reboot` for the numbers in `/etc/crontab` and put the command.

Comment: I had to replace `grep ^keymaps` by `grep -i keymaps` as in the original blog post. But then I decided to just replace the key definition in my keymap in `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/` (using a custom keymap anyway). Also: +1 for the alternative solution :D

Answer (score -3):

Adding the following line to .profile or .bash_profile should disable caps lock:

```
xmodmap -e "remove lock = Caps_Lock"
```

Comment: How do you use `xmodmap` when you're not running an X server?

Comment: I would assume Kragen is running an X server, since they mentioned GNOME's System Settings panel.

Comment: In a typical Ubuntu installation, X does not run in the `tty1` virtual console.

Comment: I tried this [in X,  ubuntu 11.04] and it's not working.  did they change it?