# not able to boot up with the key lock on

Tags: keyboard

Since installing the latest version have had to hit the key lock key to use the keypad.

How can I boot up with the key lock on?

Without not having to hit the key lock key every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the <kbd>NumLck</kbd> key, go to the software centre and search for `numlockx` or through a terminal:

```
apt-get install numlockx
```

If you're talking about the <kbd>CapsLck</kbd> key, have a look here: [How do I turn off Caps Lock (the lock, not the key) by command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80254/how-do-i-turn-off-caps-lock-the-lock-not-the-key-by-command-line)

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)