# Sticky keys: Shift starts in "locked" mode after stand-by

Tags: 18.04, accessibility

I have sticky keys enabled following an injury that prevents me from typing with my left hand.

I have some strange behaviour with the Shift key when coming out of stand-by and suspend.

When I awake my laptop from sleep (by opening the lid) my Shift key starts in a "locked" state (as if it were pressed twice in a row). When I awake it from "suspend" (after using the "Suspend" option in Unity's gear menu), the Shift key comes up as pressed once.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity 7.5.0 as my desktop. I have indicator-xkbmod from ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 installed to tell me the state of the keys.

What can I do so the Shift key doesn't get locked when I wake up my laptop? It can be really annoying if I forget it does this (which is all the time).

Comment: I think that the c/python scripts in this question can resolve this too, https://askubuntu.com/q/80254/26246 . Put that script to run after wake up to reset all modifiers locks.